# #attached property doest't work!(render array/form api)

Tags: 7

the css file style.css never get loaded when using the form api #attached properties. here is my code:

```
mymodule_menu() {

  $items['test'] = array (
            'title' => t('test css'),
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguements' => array('test_attach_css'),
            'access callback' => TRUE,
            );

return $items;

}

function test_attach_css($form,$form_state) {
   $markup = '<p class="test">style the font as red</p>';
   $form['content']['#markup']  = $markup;
   $form['content']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path("module",       "mymodule")."/style.css";


return $form;
  }
```

the content of css file:

.test {

```
 color:red;
```

}

Comment: have you tried `kpr(drupal_get_path("module", "mymodule")."/style/style.css");`?

Comment: Just to clear up any confusion - nothing in the code above uses the form API. Perhaps you can describe what you're trying to do, and why you think you need the FAPI?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. i've changed the question. i want to theme a radio form which needs a custom styling. but for some reason, i cannot load the css file with #attached property. it works if i added the styling codes in the theme's main style file.if i remember correctly, the attached property also works with render array api. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Mołot, the css file path is correct. i can access it via the browser

Answer (score 0):

after many hours of searching and debugging for an anwser, i finally realize  it's a naming issue. you cannot name the css file as style.css. i changed the name  to custom.css,then it works as expected!